# Storm UI gets hang with 'Loading topology summary'

Tags: apache-storm, ambari

I'm unable to view the topology summary in Storm UI (in Ambari). The UI gets hang with "Loading Topology Summary" message. Please help me out to resolve this issue.

Ambari version : 2.6.0.0

HDP: 2.6.3.0

Storm : 1.1.0

Regards,

Naresh.

Here is the Image
[image]

Comment: Ambari 2.6.2 is out so it may be worth upgrading to the latest to check whether it's working.

Answer (score 1):

I too ran across this recently. Turns out the metadata stored in ZK was out of date with the Broker IDs. You can read more about it and how to resolve it here: https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/197972/storm-ui-hung-with-loading-topology-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your storm state is not updated in the zookeeper. Try cleaning the current storm states from zookeeper and then restart storm from ambari UI.